# How can we implement WePay SDK in android?

Tags: android

Is it possible to integrate **WePay SDK** in android ?
As there is no any SDK for android. So can we use JAVA SDK ?
Pease help me with some ideas to achieve this.

```
Thanks
```

Comment: Have you found anything for this?

Comment: Sorry keen I could not find so far.

Comment: Thanks. Let us know by posting on this thread if you find anything useful.

Comment: I found the solution here https://github.com/wepay/wecrowd-android.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Java SDK, however it lacks some of the tokenization features of the iOS SDK. The Java SDK wraps the WePay API though so it should work for your use case.